# reactjs Click the button and it will go to another page with the ID of data

Tags: reactjs

how do i do when the user clicks the button it goes to the other page with the data or record of his choice? I search all over the Internet but i cant find any resource that can help with my problem. thanks in advance.

This is how i post my data

```
   const data = posts.map
    (post =>
      (
        {
          name: post.firstname, 
          dateregistered: post.dateregistered, 
          department: post.departmentname, 
          actions: 
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            size="small"
            className={classes.editButton}
            startIcon={<EditIcon />}>
              Edit
          </Button>,
          deactivate: 
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            size="small"
            className={classes.deactivateButton}
            startIcon={<HighlightOffIcon />}>
              Deactivate
          </Button>,
        }
      )
    )
```

this is where the the page when the user after click the button

```
const ChangeUser = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <CRow>
        <CCol xs="12" md="12">
          <CCard>
            <CCardHeader style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
              Edit User Form
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
              <CForm action="" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" className="form-horizontal">
                <CFormGroup row>
                <CCol md="2">
                    <CLabel htmlFor="text-input" style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Username:</CLabel>
                  </CCol>
                  <CCol xs="12" md="6">
                    <CInput id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="Username or E-mail..." />
                    <CFormText>Required. 150 characters of fewer. Letters,digits and @ / . / - / ! / _ only.</CFormText>
                  </CCol>
                </CFormGroup>

                <CFormGroup row>
                  <CCol md="2">
                    <CLabel htmlFor="text-input" style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>First Name:</CLabel>
                  </CCol>
                  <CCol xs="12" md="6">
                    <CInput type="text-input" id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="First Name..." autoComplete="email"/>
                    <CFormText className="help-block">Enter first name.</CFormText>
                  </CCol>
                </CFormGroup>
                <CFormGroup row>
                  <CCol md="2">
                    <CLabel htmlFor="text-input" style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Middle Name or Initial:</CLabel>
                  </CCol>
                <CFormGroup row>
                  <CCol md="2">
                    <CLabel htmlFor="text-input" style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Last Name:</CLabel>
                  </CCol>
                  <CCol xs="12" md="6">
                    <CInput type="text-input" id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="Last Name..." autoComplete="email"/>
                    <CFormText className="help-block">Enter last name.</CFormText>
                  </CCol>
                </CFormGroup>
              </CForm>
            </CCardBody>
            <CCardFooter className="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
              <CButton type="reset" size="sm" color="danger"><CIcon name="cil-ban" /> Cancel</CButton>
              <CButton type="submit" size="sm" color="primary" style={{marginLeft: 10}}><CIcon name="cil-scrubber" /> Submit</CButton>
            </CCardFooter>
          </CCard>
        </CCol>
      </CRow>
    </>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: How have you rendered the buttons? Please post all relevant codes.

Comment: nope, I dont know how to do it,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you navigate between pages with `react-router-dom`.
If that's the case, you can use

```
history.push('/path', { state: yourDataHere });
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history

and you can access your data from

```
location.state;
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location